# Translate one term differently in one program

Tags: parsing, ocaml, frontend, lexer

I try to make a frontend for a kind of programs... there are 2 particularities:

1) When we meet a string beginning with `=`, I want to read the rest of the string as a `formula` instead of a string value. For instance, `"123"`, `"TRUE"`, `"TRUE+123"` are considered having `string` as type, while `"=123"`, `"=TRUE"`, `"=TRUE+123"` are considered having `Syntax.formula` as type. By the way,

```
(* in syntax.ml *)
and expression =
  | E_formula of formula
  | E_string of string
  ...

and formula =
  | F_int of int  
  | F_bool of bool
  | F_Plus of formula * formula
  | F_RC of rc

and rc =
  | RC of int * int
```

2) Inside the formula, some strings are interpreted differently from outside. For instance, in a command `R4C5 := 4`, `R4C5` which is actually a variable, is considered as a `identifier`, while in `"=123+R4C5"` which tries to be translated to a formula, `R4C5` is translated as `RC (4,5): rc`.

So I don't know how to realize this with 1 or 2 lexers, and 1 or 2 parsers.

At the moment, I try to realize all in 1 lexer and 1 parser. Here is part of code, which doesn't work, it still considers `R4C5` as `identifier`, instead of `rc`:

```
(* in lexer.mll *)
let begin_formula =  double_quote "=" 
let end_formula = double_quote
let STRING = double_quote ([^ "=" ])* double_quote

rule token = parse
  ...
  | begin_formula { BEGIN_FORMULA }
  | 'R'      { R }
  | 'C'      { C }
  | end_formula { END_FORMULA }
  | lex_identifier as li
      { try Hashtbl.find keyword_table (lowercase li)  
        with Not_found -> IDENTIFIER li }
  | STRING as s { STRING s }
  ...

(* in parser.mly *)
expression:
| BEGIN_FORMULA f = formula END_FORMULA { E_formula f }
| s = STRING { E_string s }
...

formula:
| i = INTEGER { F_int i }
| b = BOOL { F_bool b }
| f0 = formula PLUS f1 = formula { F_Plus (f0, f1) }  
| rc { F_RC $1 }

rc:
| R i0 = INTEGER C i1 = INTEGER { RC (i0, i1) }
```

Could anyone help?

**New idea:** I am thinking of sticking on 1 lexer + 1 parser, and create a *entrypoint* for formula in lexer as what we do normally for `comment`... here are some updates in `lexer.mll` and `parser.mly`:

```
(* in lexer.mll *)
rule token = parse
...
| begin_formula { formula lexbuf }
...
| INTEGER as i { INTEGER (int_of_string i)  }
| '+'      { PLUS }
...

and formula = parse
| end_formula { token lexbuf }
| INTEGER as i { INTEGER_F (int_of_string i)  }
| 'R'      { R }
| 'C'      { C }
| '+'      { PLUS_F }
| _        { raise (Lexing_error ("unknown in formula")) }

(* in parser.mly *)
expression:
| formula { E_formula f }
...

formula:
| i = INTEGER_F { F_int i }
| f0 = formula PLUS_F f1 = formula { F_Plus (f0, f1) }  
...
```

I have done some tests, for instance to parse `"=R4"`, the problem is that it can parse well `R`, but it considers `4` as `INTEGER` instead of `INTEGER_F`, it seems that `formula lexbuf` needs to be added from time to time in the body of `formula` entrypoint (Though I don't understand why parsing in the body of `token` entrypoint works without always mentioning `token lexbuf`). I have tried several possibilities: `| 'R' { R; formula lexbuf }`,  `| 'R' { formula lexbuf; R }`, etc. but it didn't work... ... Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest choice would be to have two different lexers and two different parsers; call the lexer&parser for formulas from inside the global parser. After the fact you can see how much is shared between the two grammars, and factorize things when possible.

Comment: gasche and @didierc, I think maybe we can add a entrypoint for formula to translate formula differently... Could you please take a look at the new update in my OP?